# How to make scrollable text with the link?

Tags: android, hyperlink, scroll, textview

I use the following code to make the text view scrollable:

```
TextView mTextView6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wizard6_text1);
mTextView6.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

and the following code to make links (given as `<a href="http://example.com">example</a>`) clickable:

```
mTextView6.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

It works well separately. But how should I use it together?

Comment: just use LinkMovementMethod as it is ScrollingMovementMethod as well

Comment: @pskink, thanks! Please post that as the answer, so I will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use LinkMovementMethod as it is ScrollingMovementMethod as well

Comment: I used only LinkMovementMethod but it did not work. TextView does not scroll. Could you please tell me how you solve this problem?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/util/Linkify.java#334